# How can I load custom Django tags from a file?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I have a tag definition for mytag in a mytag.py file. This works fine when I'm using a Django project with a settings.py and INSTALLED_APPS -- I append 'myapp' to the list and place mytag.py in myapp/templatetags.

Now I'm using django.conf.settings.configure and I don't have a module with a templatetags subdirectory -- how can I load mytag.py?

---

**Update:**

I now tried to use a module with a templatetags directory, but I can't get it to work. Here's my setup:

Files:

- myapp

  - `__init.py__`
  - templatetags

    - `__init__.py`
    - mytag.py
- program

  - test.py
  - test.html

This is the relevant code:

```
# test.py

from django.template import Template, Context
from django.conf import settings

from mostlystatic.processors.mostlystaticprocessor import MostlystaticProcessor
from mostlystatic.stuff import DebugLogger

import sys
sys.path.append("~/")

settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True,
    INSTALLED_APPS = ("myapp",)
    )

t = Template(open("test.html").read())
c = Context({})
content = t.render(c)

print content

# test.html

{% load mytag %}

# mytag.py (doesn't load)

from classytags.arguments import Argument
from classytags.core import Tag, Options
from django import template

register = template.Library()

class MyTag(Tag):
    name="mytag"

    def render_tag(self, context:
        return "test"

register.tag(MyTag)
```

When I run test.py I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    t = Template(open("test.html").read())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 153, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 270, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1033, in load
    (taglib, e))
django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'mytag' is not a valid tag library: Template library mytag not found, tried django.templatetags.mytag
```

Comment: You want to include your tags from an app that doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: "I used to have <something that follows the documentation>, now I want to do <something that completely breaks the way projects are supposed to be configured>, how can I do that?"

Comment: @arie I still have the tags file, I only used the app for testing it.

Comment: @Daniel I was hoping there might be a standalone way to do this, like there is with other parts of the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is make a module with a `templatetags` subdirectory, and include that module in `INSTALLED_APPS` when you configure the settings.

Any other approach is going to involve wrestling with the Django internals.

If your script doesn't work, try stripping it down to something really simple like below, then build it back up.

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(INSTALLED_APPS=('my_app',))

from django.template import Template
# my_tags does not exist, but the error shows that it is 
# searching my_app's template tag directory
Template.render("{% load my_tags %}")
TemplateSyntaxError: 'my_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library my_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.my_tags, my_app.templatetags.my_tags
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. It's not ideal but I think it will do.

Comment: I tried it but it still isn't working. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I can't see the problem, but I can get a simple example to work, which I've added to my answer. Start with that, then build it up.

Comment: Are you sure that it's working? It says it could not find the library. When I rename my_app to something random - a directory that can't be searched - I still get the same result.

Comment: Yes, it's working. The key thing is that it looked for `my_app.templatetags.my_tags`. In your error message, it only looked for `django.templatetags.mytag`, which suggests that my_app is not an installed app.

Comment: Ok I might just install it then. Do you see anything wrong with my sys.path.append? I have the folder in "~/myapp".

Comment: I don't know whether your sys path is correct or not. Note that Django only populates the list of template tag modules once per thread, so if that happens before you set `INSTALLED_APPS`, then you're too late. Configuring the settings should be the very first thing your script does. Having said that, I would just add the app to `settings.INSTALLED` apps. It's not really worth fighting against Django in this case.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks a lot for all the help and for being so patient.